# SQL: filter a joined table

Tags: sql

I have two tables that have a one-many relationship, and I would like to put together a query that follows a rule to join a particular row in the 'many' table to a row in the 'one' table.

user table:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║  name        ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ user 1       ║ 
║  2 ║ user 2       ║
║  3 ║ user 3       ║
║  4 ║ user 4       ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

Messages table:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ id ║  Text        ║ user_id   ║   date  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ Hello        ║    1      ║  3/31   ║
║  2 ║ World        ║    1      ║  4/1    ║
║  3 ║ Test message ║    2      ║  4/2    ║
║  4 ║ Another test ║    3      ║  4/4    ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

I am trying to perform a single join from user to messages to get the most recent message for the user. user 2 would have 'test message', user 3 would have 'another test'. User 1 is the one I cannot figure out - I would like to have one row for user 1 returned 'world', based on the fact that it has the most recent date, but I do not see a join that has the capability to perform filtering on a joined table.

Comment: You can do this fairly easy using subqueries or window functions, but the syntax relies completely on the type of SQL you're using.  Which language are you trying to do this with?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm on SQL Server 2012... I am looking at 'window functions' as you recommend, Rodkey, and based off the descriptions I am seeing on the web and the suggestions below, I think that is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    message_id
    , [user_id]
    , name
    , [Text]
    , [date]
FROM
(
SELECT
    M.id AS message_id
    , U.id AS [user_id]
    , name
    , [Text]
    , [date]
    --Rank rows for each users by date
    , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY M.[user_id] ORDER BY [date] DESC, M.id DESC) AS Rnk
FROM
    @messages AS M
    INNER JOIN
    @users AS U
        ON M.[user_id] = U.id
) AS Tmp
WHERE
    --The latest date
    Tmp.Rnk  = 1
```

This code work in SQL Server 2012 and newer.

[image: This code work in SQL Server 2012 and newer.]

Comment: The "most recent message" should also consider the `message_id`, hence `RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY M.[user_id] ORDER BY [date] DESC, message_id DESC)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. This variant will be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can join the tables and than filter the results:

```
select tbl.name , tbl.Text from
(select User.name,
        Messages.Text,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY User.name ORDER BY Messages.date desc) AS  rank  
from User inner join Messages 
on User.id = Messages.user_id) as tbl
where rank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you started:

```
select u.id, u.name, m.text
from User u
inner join Messages m on m.user_id = u.id
inner join (
    select m.user_id, MAX(date) as max_date
    from User u
    inner join Messages m on m.user_id = u.id
    group by m.user_id
) t on t.user_id = m.user_id and m.date = t.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one. It should work :

```SQL
select user_ID,
text,
u.name,
max(date) from user u inner join messages m on m.user_id=u.id group by user_ID,
text,
u.name
```